# MySQL group rows info columns based on column values within one table

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask for help. I'm trying to combine multiple rows into multiple rows-columns.
Here's the table a want to group:

`+----+------+--------+--------+-------+
| id | type | index1 | index2 | value |
+----+------+--------+--------+-------+
| 33 | v1   |      1 |      8 | 1a    |
| 33 | v1   |      2 |      6 | 1b    |
| 33 | v1   |      3 |      3 | 1c    |
| 33 | v2   |        |      3 | 2x    |
| 33 | v2   |        |      8 | 2y    |
| 33 | v2   |        |      6 | 2z    |
| 34 | v1   |      1 |      5 | 1ass  |
| 34 | v1   |      2 |      3 | 1bss  |
| 34 | v1   |      3 |      4 | 1css  |
| 34 | v2   |        |      3 | 2xss  |
| 34 | v2   |        |      4 | 2yss  |
| 34 | v2   |        |      5 | 2zss  |
+----+------+--------+--------+-------+`

Index1 is used to keep order of index2 and to connect it with v2 type values.

This is how the result should look like:

`+----+--------+--------+------+------+
| id | index1 | index2 |  v1  |  v2  |
+----+--------+--------+------+------+
| 33 |      1 |      8 | 1a   | 2y   |
| 33 |      2 |      6 | 1b   | 2z   |
| 33 |      3 |      3 | 1c   | 2x   |
| 34 |      1 |      5 | 1ass | 2zss |
| 34 |      2 |      3 | 1bss | 2xss |
| 34 |      3 |      4 | 1css | 2yss |
+----+--------+--------+------+------+`

Thanks,
T.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you want:

```
select
    t1.id,
    t1.index1,
    t1.index2, 
    t1.value v1
    t2.value v2
from (
    select *
    from your_table
    where type = 'v1'
) t1 left join (
    select *
    from your_table
    where type = 'v2'
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.index2 = t2.index2;
```

Comment: Ok got it :) I had incorrect values in my table. Just added additional JOINs and it works like intended. THANKS!